# MultipartFile is only supported where dart:io is available

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to upload images from a web browser, I receive an exception: “**Unsupported operation: MultipartFile is only supported where dart:io is available.**”

Environment I am currently using:

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 2.10.1 at /Users/macbook/Documents/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision db747aa133 (3 months ago), 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
• Engine revision ab46186b24
• Dart version 2.16.1
• DevTools version 2.9.2
```

Does anybody know what could the issue ?

Comment: This might help answer your question: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98208

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `MultipartFile.fromPath` in the browser because the browser does not give arbitrary access to the filesystem.

If you implement file picking using what is available in the browser you can create a `MultipartFile` [from a `String`](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.fromString.html) or [from bytes](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.fromBytes.html) in the browser.

Comment: I tried to use MultipartFile.fromBytes -> backend returns "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.". When I use MultipartFile.fromString -> frontend returns error "FormatException: Invalid UTF-8 byte (at offset 0)". I am using XFile from https://pub.dev/packages/camera plugin. MultipartFile.fromBytes works without problems on mobile.

Comment: You might need to set the `contentType` for the server to know how to decode it.